# DLL dependant on curllib.dll - How can I fix this?

Tags: c++, dll, libcurl

I'm new to developing in C++. I've developed a dll where I'm using curllib to make HTTP requests.

When running the dll via depend.exe it notifies me that my dll now depends on the curllib.dll. This simply doesn't work for me. My dll is set as a static library not shared and will be distributed on its own. I cannot rely on a user having libcurl.dll installed.

I thought by including libcurl into my project this is all that would be needed and my dll could be independent.

If this is impossible to resolve is there an alternative method I can use to create HTTP requests? Obviously I would prefer to use libcurl.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile curl as a lib instead of a dll by opening the solution file in visual studio and changing the build project to "lib release". Thus you wont need the dll at all and you can just include the lib in the linker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually need the dll for distribution purposes and for some reason I've attempted to build it as a lib already as I've been through every setting and It didn't output any files for me. Only the dll release seems to create a set of files.

Comment: It should be outputted to curl\lib\LIB-Release\libcurl.lib

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact file I need to download?